# numbers and toFixed , toPrecision in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Regarding the famous issue of  `1.01+1.02` which is `2.0300000000000002`

one of the workarounds is to use `toFixed` : e.g.

```
(1.01+1.02).toFixed(2) --->"2.03"
```

But I saw a solution with toPrecision

```
parseFloat((1.01+1.02).toPrecision(10))-->"2.03"
```

But lets have a look at `n` in

- `toFixed(n)`
- `toPrecision(n)`

How would I know what is n ?

```
  0.xxxxxxxxxxx
+
  0.yyyyyyyyyyyyy
---------------------
  0.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
                ^ 
                |
-----??????------
```

each number being added can have a different decimal digits...

for example :

`1.0002+1.01+1.03333`--> 3.0435300000000005

how would I calculate the `n` here ? what is the best practice for this (specific) issue ?

Comment: I never knew this issue existed... Maybe something like `.toString().length` could be used to get the length of the longest number, to use in `.toPrecision(n)` ?

Comment: Why do you want to "figure out" `n`? I'd only apply `toFixed` and friends when I'm outputting values to the user, in that case I make a decision based on the case for how many decimal places I want.

Comment: @phant0m I presume it is because he wants to know the true value of the calculation rather than having the extra digits floating points inherently gain. He may just want to show it in the smallest precision capable of showing the exact value of the calculation.

Comment: @phant0m: the problem is that JavaScript adds those stray numbers, and these could theoretically interfere with other calculations, meaning you'd have to fix that during the calculations, instead of at the last moment, when you output the value. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPFS2/1/) displays the problem.

Comment: In that case, it may be better to use an arbitrary precision library. Even if you do cut off "stray numbers", you may not be able to represent the number accurately in a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the expected output:

```
function add(){
    // Initialize output and "length" properties
    var length = 0;
    var output = 0;
    // Loop through all arguments supplied to this function (So: 1,4,6 in case of add(1,4,6);)
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        // If the current argument's length as string is longer than the previous one (or greater than 0 in case of the first argument))
        if(arguments[0].toString().length > length){
            // Set the current length to the argument's length (+1 is to account for the decimal point taking 1 character.)
            length = arguments[0].toString().length +1;
        }
        // Add the current character to the output with a precision specified by the longest argument.
        output = parseFloat((output+arguments[i]).toPrecision(length));
    }
    // Do whatever you with with the result, here. Usually, you'd 'return output;'
    console.log(output);
}
add();                     // Returns 0
add(1,2,3);                // Returns 6
add(1.01,2.01,3.03);       // Returns 6.05
add(1.01,2.0213,3.3333);   // Returns 6.3646
add(11.01,2.0213,31.3333); // Returns 44.3646
```

`parseFloat` even gets rid of trailing zero's for you.

This function accepts as many numbers as parameters as you wish, then adds these together taking the numbers' string length into account, when adding them. The precision used in the addition is dynamically modified to fit the "currently added" argument's length.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9HKX/3/)

Comment: Don't just post code.  Actually explain your answer and reasoning.  Yes most of us here can read your code and understand it, however giving code and no explanation often does not help people to learn.

Comment: In the for loop , i think you mean arguments[i]

Comment: @RoyiNamir: you're right! Could you edit it for me? I'm on my phone now.

Answer (score 1):

For addition as in this situation I would check the number of decimal places in each operand.

In the simplest of situations the number of decimal places in the operand with the greatest number of decimal places is the value of n.

Once you have this, use which ever method you like to truncate your value.  Then get rid of trailing zeros.

You may encounter trailing zeros in situations such as 1.06 + 1.04, the first step would take you to 1.10 then truncating the zero would give 1.1

**In your last example 1.0002+1.01+1.03333 greatest number of decimal places is 5 so you are left with 3.04353 and there are no trailing zeros to truncate.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing calculations, you have a couple of choices:

- multiply the numbers by eg 100, to convert to integers, then do the calculations, then convert back again
- do the calculations, dont worry about the rounding errors, then round the result at display time

If you're dealing with money/currencies, the first option is probably not a bad option.  If you're just doing scientific maths, I would personally not worry about it, and just round the results at display time, eg to 6 significant figures which is the default for my c++ compiler (gcc; not sure if it is in the c++ standards or not, but if you print `1.234567890` in gcc c++, the output is `1.23457`, and the problem is avoided)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 216.57421;

a.toPrecision(1); // => '200' because 216 with 1 < 5;
a.toPrecision(2); // => '220' because 216 with 6 >= 5;

a.toFixed(1); // => 216.6 because 7 >= 5;
a.toFixed(2); // => 216.57 because 4 < 5;
```